# Where to put a specific question:  online banking program (Jameica/Hibiscus)

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a Question about a specific open-source online banking program (Jameica/Hibiscus) and do not know where to put it. I have browsed the StackExchange network and, even though all portals are categorized and neatly displayed, by now there are so many I felt a bit overwhelmed.
However, I don't think any question about that tool has so far ever been asked on any of the portals, and I wouldn't know where to ask.

Is the topic no suited for the Network, because it is to specific and there's possibly not enough user-base interested in the topics? should I resort to the official forum of the tool?

If not, if there's something new that I don't know, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

If you're working on the *code* for the program, put it on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) . If you're installing it, then probably [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

If you're just a *user* of the program, then [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) if it's a desktop app, and [webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) if it's a web app.